# Drop Down Menu on Hover Shows but doesn't stay?

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

My Navbar has drop down menus, on hover  the drop down menus display perfectly, however its impossible to click on the items on the menu, as soon as you move the cursor from the main nav it disappears , I tried adding display:block , z-index ...but the problem hasn't been fixed

**CSS**

```
    #ime-nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
background:#FF9900;

}


#ime-nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: fixed;

}

#ime-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    alignment-adjust:central;
}

#ime-nav li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:195px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#ime-nav li:hover a {
    background: #F7931E;
}

#ime-nav li:hover ul  a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#ime-nav li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #333333;
    color: #fff;


}

#ime-nav li ul {
    display: none;
}

#ime-nav li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

#ime-nav li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#ime-nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;

/*this is where I'm trying to fix the problem*/ 

}

.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


@media screen and (max-width : 760px){

    #ime-nav ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    #ime-nav li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    #ime-nav ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #ime-nav .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <body>

<div id="ime-nav">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><img src="navigate.png" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="icon_nav.png" /></a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nav_libraryicon.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">News and Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Library ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Thermal Power Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mechatronics Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Freshman Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Library</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Learn ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Pro Engineer/ Creo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autocad</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Matlab </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Microsoft Excel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lab Episodes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Virtual Registration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>



    </ul>



  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 #ime-nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
   display: block;
   /*this is where I'm trying to fix the problem*/ 
 }
```

Use like this

```
 #ime-nav ul li:hover ul{display:block}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n0buqLkn/)

Comment: That fixed the main problem , but now 
#ime-nav .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
is always visible , Its supposed to only show when you resize the screen 

here's an image to explain : http://i.imgur.com/ckMa1fi.png